# Is it possible to format text using markdown inside a markdown table?

Tags: markdown, multimarkdown

I need to be able to build a markdown only table with formatted text inside (html inside the table is not an option).
It seems that the h3 is not applied by markdown parsers:

```
| | | 
| --- | ---- | 
| ### WHAT DID YOU LEARN ON YOUR JOURNEY? |   |
```

Does anyone knows how to have this h3 formatted as a h3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables are a non-standard feature of Markdown and are not well defined. However, one thing that is consistent across most implementations is that they do not support block level content. In other words, there is no support for a header within a table cell.

However, you can certainly use bold, italic, etc.:

```
| | | 
| --- | ---- | 
| **WHAT DID YOU LEARN ON YOUR JOURNEY?** |   |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get away with an HTML `<span>` element with a `class` attribute - that points to CSS.